# Change target CPU settings in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, x86, anycpu

I wish to change the target CPU settings from "Any CPU" to "x86" in Visual Studio 2010.

I read on another website that I need to do the following:

1. Go to the startup project of your program.
2. Open the properties window.
3. Click the compile tab.
4. Click advanced compile options.
5. Change the target CPU options to x86.

But I don't see the "compile" tab anywhere in the properties.

Please help me at the earliest.

*Update: I do see a platform dropdown, but that contains nothing apart from "Any CPU"*,

[image: Platform contains nothing apart from "Any CPU"].

Comment: Do you see this screen: http://gchandra.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/compiletab.png ?

Comment: Nope. i didnt. I see this: http://img574.imageshack.us/img574/2949/screenshot20101105at146.png

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe the reason you don't see the Compile tab in the project properties is because you're using the Express edition. Optimization for a specific CPU type is not offically supported in this edition. However, you should be able to change the active solution platform in the following way:

From the "Tools" menu, select the "Options" item, and then select the "Projects and Solutions" option in the listbox on the left-hand side of the Options dialog. (You might have to check "Show all settings" first.) Check the box that says "Show advanced build configurations":

[image: Screenshot of the options dialog to enable "Show advanced build configurations"]

Then, on the "Build" menu, see if you have an item called "Configuration Manager". If not, you need to add the item to the menu (right-click on any area in the toolbar and choose "Customize" at the bottom of the list).

Once you've opened the Configuration Manager dialog, go to the "Active solution platform" drop-down box and choose "New". From the "New Solution Platform" dialog that appears, you should be able to choose "x86" from the first drop-down box.

Alternatively, it looks like you can manually edit the project file to specify the CPU type. See *[Changing the target CPU in VB Express 2008](http://www.onteorasoftware.net/post/Changing-the-target-cpu-in-VB-express-2008.aspx)*. It looks like it amounts to simply changing the `<PlatformTarget>` under the first `<PropertyGroup>` section to "x86".

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the info. I'm looking at the tools menu but i dont see the "Projects and Solutions" option. Is that an express problem too ?

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that... You're actually looking for the "Options" item on the Tools menu. Then in the Options dialog, Projects and Solutions is one of the options in the listbox on the left-hand side. You might have to check "Show all settings" at the bottom if it doesn't show up.

Comment: Excellent! You're welcome. I think this is a great question because I imagine you're not the only one to run into this kind of limitation with VS Express.

Comment: Cody, can you please advise why for Console App in Visual studio build configuration manager I can see only `x86` platform, though I can select any CPU platform tartget in project properties tab?

Comment: @Johnny_D Uh, I'm guessing that it isn't appearing in the build configuration manager because you haven't actually created the platform target yet.

Answer (score 8):

To make the *Build* menu bar appear on your Visual Studio 2010, go to menu Tools -> Settings -> check Expert Settings. So later on you can use Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Visual Studio 2010 right now, but in Visual Studio 2008, you have to first add a configuration through `Build -> Configuration Manager`.

After you have added the configuration, you can simply select the Active Configuration through the drop down menu.

Comment: but how do i know what configuration it is for an x86 system ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Visual Studio 2010 right now, but in Visual Studio 2008, you have to first add a configuration through `Build -> Configuration Manager`.

After you have added the configuration, you can simply select the `Active Configuration` through the drop down menu.