# How to make vb.net application that works at dual platforms (32/64 bit)

Tags: .net, vb.net, 32bit-64bit, anycpu

Can I create an application that can work on both windows platforms (32 / 64 bit ) at the same time  ? if no , how can i create 64bit version and 32bit version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - just set the compile option in Vizual Studio to AnyCPU (`Build>Configuration Manager>Active Solution Platform`). To Target 32bit or 64 bit set the platform to x86 or x64 respectively

Have a look at [this link explaining the differences](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/)

But AnyCPU is not necessarily the best option - so have a look at this article: [AnyCPU is it evil](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/502739-Any-CPU-Is-it-evil) and make up your own mind what setting you would like

If you are using Visual Studio Express then have a look at [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104228/change-target-cpu-settings-in-visual-studio-2010-express) explaining how to do this

Comment: Ok thank you Matt for help . But I have only 86x platform , I can't find AnyCPU or 64bit

Comment: @user1970090 - `Build>Configuration Manager>Active Solution Platform` then select `New...` from the dropdown

Comment: Are these apply to express 2010 studio ? because there's no build tab , neither in in project settings .

Comment: IMHO is *AnyCPU is it evil* nonsense! You just need to keep in mind that you need to add x86 and x64 dlls. That is very simple.