# Running command line script from C# tool failing

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, command-line, cmd

I want to run the below code from my application:

`manage-bde -protectors -disable C:`

It is working perfectly if I open up a command prompt and run from there (win8).

But if I try to run it from my app, I get: `'manage-bde' is not a recognized program.`

My code:

```
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C manage-bde -protectors -disable C:";
            process1.Start();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for Failure:**

cmd.exe could not identify your file`manage-bde` to proceed further.

You can solve this issue by providing proper path for the file `manage-bde`.

**Solution 1:**
When you run any console Commands from C# they will run from the following path by default:

if you run the project in Release Mode  --> `<Solution FolderName>\<Project FolderName>\bin\Release`

if you run the project in Debug Mode  --> `<Solution FolderName>\<Project FolderName>\bin\Debug`

So if you want to run any thirdparty exe files from your c# code you make sure to copy them(exe files) into respective folders.

**Solution 2 :** You can set the path for `manage-bde` in Environment Variables

**Solution 3:**
You can give the Full Path of `manage-bde` in your code.

Sample Code : here i'm providing complete path of exe/bat file which i would like to execute:

```
Process process1 = new Process();
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C C:\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin\jmeter.bat";
process1.Start();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I defined the full path, but I get the same: "'C:\Windows\System32\manage-bde.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." The executable exists.

Comment: @fishmong3r : it is because version mismatch as you running it in windows 7. so from Visual Studio please right click on project -> properties->Build->change your platform Target from anycpu to X64, then build and run the project it should be able to execute your exe :)

Comment: OK, I admit I'm a noob but I can't find this option. I'm using VS C# Express 2010. In the project properties -> build tab I have no 'Target'.

Comment: @fishmong3r : From the "Tools" menu, select the "Options" item, and then select the "Projects and Solutions" option in the listbox on the left-hand side of the Options dialog. (You might have to check "Show all settings" first.) Check the box that says "Show advanced build configurations".      -->Source>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104228/change-target-cpu-settings-in-visual-studio-2010-express

Comment: Ok, wait a sec, I'm checking.

Comment: Yeah, no. I followed the instructions on that link but I can't get to Configuration Manager. Now I can see the 'Platform' on the Build tab, but I can't choose anything but 'Active(x86)'.

Comment: I made it. And I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: :) you are welcome. could you please tell me how did you manage to get X64 bit option in build settings?

Comment: Sure, I could finally add from Soulution Explorer -> Property pages -> Configuration Properties -> Configuration -> and I've changed the platform to x64

Comment: But now I'm facing the issue that I can't run my app on a Win7 32-bit OS. Can I somehow make the app working regardless of the OS architecture?